# Regex to match begining of string with set endings or not

Tags: javascript, regex

Looking for the regex that will match whatever is at the beginning of a string minus one of the following set endings:

```
_A
_B
_C
_ZZ
```

So for example:

```
1. blah         needs to match blah
2. blah_A       needs to match blah
3. blahblah_A   needs to match blahblah
4. blah_D       needs to match blah_D
5. blah_Z       needs to match blah_Z
6. blah_ZZ      needs to match blah
7. blah_Ablah   needs to match blah_Ablah
```

Unsuccessful attemps that I have tried are:

```
.*(?=(_(A|B|C|ZZ)))
  did not match 1,4,5, and 7 correctly

.*([^(_A$)]|[^(_B$)]|[^(_C$)]|[^(_ZZ$)])
  did not match any correctly
```

Regex vesrion used is javascript

Anyone got any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that `.*` can consume the entire string (and it will). The simplest fix is to make the repetition ungreedy and require the end of the string after the optional `_` endings:

```
.*?(?=(_(A|B|C|ZZ))?$)
```

This way `.*` won't consume the ending characters if they should be excluded.

[Working demo.](http://regexpal.com/?flags=gm&regex=.%2a%3F%28%3F%3D%28_%28A%7CB%7CC%7CZZ%29%29%3F%24%29&input=blah%0Ablah_A%0Ablahblah_A%0Ablah_D%0Ablah_Z%0Ablah_ZZ%0Ablah_Ablah)

As a minor optimisation, you could avoid the capturing group (if you don't need it) and use a character class, for the single-character endings:

```
.*?(?=(?:_(?:[ABC]|ZZ))?$)
```